# Place an image above a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

The image is placed beside the navigation bar to the left, not above the navigation bar.

I want the image to be placed above the navigation bar, not beside it.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00003f;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropbtn,
.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #3f61a1;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #3f61a1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/ERAU_WW_0809.png" alt="Flying Fixed Wing drone" style="display: block; float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px" ; width="400" title="Flying Fixed Wing drone" />
<nav class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="index.html" title="x"> Computer Information &amp; Download Versions </a>
  <a href="FAQ's.html" title="x"> FAQ </a>
  <a href="faq.html" title="x"> Hub Resources</a>
  <a href="table.html" title="x"> Technical Assistance &amp; Contact Information</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: In addition, your HTML is invalid. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove the `float: left` in the CSS

Comment: No change to position, but the formatting for the navigation bar was impacted.

Comment: did you try to remove it also in the style attribute of the img?

Comment: Not from css. try with remove float: left from img  style

Comment: Attempted both responses. No change.

Answer (score 0):

check the below code :

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00003f;
}

.bannerImg {
  display: block;
 padding-right: 10px; 
 padding-bottom: 10px";
 width="400"
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropbtn,
.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #3f61a1;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #3f61a1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/ERAU_WW_0809.png" alt="Flying Fixed Wing drone" class="bannerImg" title="Flying Fixed Wing drone" />
<nav class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="index.html" title="x"> Computer Information &amp; Download Versions </a>
  <a href="FAQ's.html" title="x"> FAQ </a>
  <a href="faq.html" title="x"> Hub Resources</a>
  <a href="table.html" title="x"> Technical Assistance &amp; Contact Information</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This works when I run the snippet in the browser but not my code. I am currently combing through the css and html to find anything else that may be modifying it.